# NodeJS and HTML5 Websockets not working together

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I have installed NodeJS on my Ubuntu machine and have created the following script....

```
var host = 'localhost'
var port = '8080'
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        socket.write(data);
    });
}).listen(port, host);

console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
```

I then run...

```
node example.js
```

...in a terminal, which gives me the following...

```
Server running at http://localhost:8080/
```

I created a simple HTML page with the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
      <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(!("WebSocket" in window)) {
                alert("Sorry, the build of your browser does not support WebSockets.");
                return;
            }

            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");

            ws.onclose = function() {
                alert("socket closed");
            };
            ws.onopen = function() {
                alert("socked opened");
            };
            ws.onmessage = function() {
                alert("message received");
            };

            $( 'button' ).click( function() {
                ws.send( "testing" );
            });

            setInterval( function() {
                $( 'p.readyState' ).text( ws.readyState );
            }, 1000 );
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <p class="readyState"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I browse to the page I get no feedback and the readyState is always 0. If I stop the server whilst the page is still open I get the socket closed alert.

I have tested this script in Chrome (8.0.552.215), Firefox 4 (Beta 7) and Opera 11 (Beta).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't running a WebSocket server, you're running a HTTP server. I wrote a [tutorial on WebSockets and Node.js](http://joshuakehn.com/2010/9/22/WebSocket-Tutorial-with-Nodejs.html), try reading through that for a more detailed explanation.

You need to elevate the connection to a WebSocket connection because a WS connection uses a standard HTTP request initially. Create a server around [Node's WebSocket Server](https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server) implementation instead of `net`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which provides a common cross browser API, transparently using whatever the browser supports (including websockets). The official server side implementation is in NodeJS. It was suggested in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6524/450#6526).

[Firefox has disabled Websockets](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/) in the upcoming pre-release because of a serious [security vulnerability](http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/websocket.pdf) at the protocol level. Opera has announced to do the same in version 11.